# ¿Como puedo cambiar el fondo (BackGround ) de un screen utilizando un botón en Android Studio?

Tags: android, imagen, botón

Quiero que se cambie a una imagen, utilice esta sintaxis pero solo puedo usar colores y lo que quiero es una imagen:

```
b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBackGround);
    ll=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con: `11.setBackgroundResource(nombre_imagen);`

`nombre_imagen()` retorna el id de la imagen que está en el `Drawable`.`

***Ejemplo: en la imagen muestra en la carpeta que exsite solo un archivo llamado android.jpg***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quedaría así : `11.setBackgroundResource(android);`

*Recuerda que tus imágenes debes guardarlas en aquella carpeta.*

Ten cuidado con el manejo de imágenes de alta resolución, aveces pueden sobre-cargar tu app, Puedes usar librerías como [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) para el manejo de memoria y no se vuelta lenta tu app.

Comment: ¡Me funciono! Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Que bueno que te haya funcionado, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de Ash es válida y yo la daría por correcta, por dar mas soluciones, aquí tienes otra manera.

```
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.tu_nombre_imagen);

BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
tu_Layout.setBackground(background);
```

Este método es para Api 16 o superior, si estas haciendo una aplicación con una Api mínima de 15 o inferior, para que esta forma funcione debes añadir `@TargetApi(16)` en el método donde coloques este trozo de código.